# Creating a file location through the API, Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

Is it possible to create a [File Location](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/file_transfer_location/) with the API? I can't find documentation about this. My client has 130 business units and need to implement the same file location on every BU. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way  way to do this, as far as I know.

And with the coming FTP password policy change apocalypse, it sure would be nice to even just retrieve the basic File Location info.